# Excluding/omitting rows from report based on values in a column

Tags: oracle

I'll try to explain my issue the best I can:

```
SELECT ISSUE, COLUMN_B, COLUMN_C, COLUMN_D, COLUMN_E, SECONDARY_ISSUE
FROM 
TABLE_A
WHERE
ISSUE NOT LIKE 'VALUE_1'
AND ISSUE NOT LIKE 'VALUE_2'
AND ISSUE NOT LIKE 'VALUE_3'
AND COLUMN_E IS NOT NULL
```

Under the [SECONDARY_ISSUE] column, there are two different values currently and NULL values. I need to add to my WHERE criteria to filter out one or more [SECONDARY_ISSUE] values, but show the other values and the NULL's in the report results. [ISSUE_CODE] is always NOT NULL.

I tried adding the following to my statement:

```
AND SECONDARY_CODE NOT IN (SELECT SECONDARY_ISSUE FROM TABLE_A WHERE SECONDARY_ISSUE='VALUE_A')
```

However, this results in data where only [SECONDARY_ISSUE='VALUE_B'] shows up with no NULL results. Many of the rows involving [ISSUE_CODE] have NULL [SECONDARY_ISSUE] fields, and I need those to appear in the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the following statement to the end of your WHERE clause:

```
AND (SECONDARY_ISSUE IS NULL OR SECONDARY_ISSUE != 'VALUE_A')
```

Comment: This answer accomplished what I needed it to, and I've found out how to add multiple entries for future-proofing. Thank you!

Is there a short explanation of what the [!] does or a resource where I can study it?

Comment: @katfysh Adding the exclamation mark (!) in front of the equals sign changes the meaning to "not equals". You can alternatively write not equals as <>.